# Connecting to a remote RabbitMQ server using letsencrypt ssl

Tags: spring-amqp

I have this configuration to be able to connect to compose.io rabbitmq service

```
package com.gandalf.configuration;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class SpringAmqpConfiguration {

    @Bean 
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() { 
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setAddresses("portal274-33.***,....");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("amqpuser"); 
    connectionFactory.setPassword("muggledone");
    connectionFactory.setUseSsl(true); 
    return connectionFactory; 
    } 


    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        //If you want a fixed number of consumers, omit the max.
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

}
```

However, upon running the program, i get an error in this line

`connectionFactory.setUseSsl(true);`

This is the error i get

```
 Compilation failure
/SpringAmqpConfiguration.java:[24,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setUseSsl(boolean)
[ERROR]   location: variable connectionFactory of type org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory
```

Why is `connectionFactory.setUseSsl(true);` not being found?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `useSsl` on the `CachingConnectionFactory`; there **is** a `useSslProtocol` property on the underlying `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory`.

Use `connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().useSslProtocol()`.

Comment: The method is actually "useSslProtocol()" instead of "setUseSslProtocol()" but otherwise correct.